# How could I check the number of files in a folder without counting them?

Tags: folders, file

Is there a way to check the number of files in a folder on MacBook, other than manually counting them?

Answer (score 2):

- Set Finder to show icons
- Access view options with <kbd>Cmd-J</kbd>
- Enable "Show item info" option (where it says "Objektinfo einblenden" in the screenshot below)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the command:

```
$ ls -A | wc -l
```

What you're doing here is *piping* the output to another Unix function called `wc` (word count) and counting each line individually (the `-l` flag).  The `ls -A` command will list all entries including files/folders starting with a `.` (which are not visible from Finder usually), only excluding `.` and `..` (which stand for the current directory and the parent directory, respectively).